# Display large text from BufferedReader into viewPager fragments (text reader type implementation)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, bufferedreader

Im trying to make a reader app wherein the data is completely static. So i have saved that data in text files in the assets folder. I want to read that data using a `bufferedReader` and display it in a `viewPager`. As the user goes on swiping to the right, pages should be added to the `viewPager` along with data from the `bufferedReader` if there is data to display.

This is my getItem function inside the viewPagerAdapter.

```
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            InputStream file = context.getAssets().open("chap1.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine = reader.readLine();
            while (mLine != null) {
                //process line
                sb.append(mLine);
                sb.append("\n");
                mLine = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }
        }
        //Log.e("READ TEXT", sb.toString());
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("content", sb.toString());
        pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return pageFragment;
    }
```

I dont want the pages to have scroll views.

How can I achieve this?
How can I limit the text read from the bufferedReader?
Or how can I split the text data and add it to different fragments? 
If my problem is not clear, please ask questions. Im not able to explain properly.
PS: Any other approach is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this is going to help**

```
package com.admin.viewpagerex;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int WordsNumber = 100;
    int WordCounter = 0;
    String content ;


    Context context;


    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context1) {
        super(fm);
        context = context1;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            MyFragment  myFragment = new MyFragment();
            loadContent();
            myFragment.setContent(content);
            WordsNumber = WordCounter + 100;
            myFragment.pageNumber = position++;

        return myFragment;

    }


    private void loadContent() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader file = new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("yourtext.txt"));
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
            StringBuffer PageWriter = new StringBuffer();
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.hasNext()&& WordCounter < WordsNumber) {
                String words = reader.next();
                if (i == WordCounter) {
                    PageWriter.append(words + " ");
                    WordCounter++;
                }
                i++;
            }

            content = PageWriter.toString();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 16; // number of pages 
    }




}
```

and in your fragment add setContent() method like this

```
public void setContent(String pagetext) {
        content = pagetext; // make sure the content is global String variable
    }
```